# Xcode doesn't Validate build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

So I want to send my build to iTunes connect. So I manually changed the version and build to 1.1 in Xcode. Then in Xcode when I click Windows -->Organizer, it still says version is 1.0.0. How do I change it to make it say version 1.1?

I tried maybe by clicking validate but it said version 1.0.0 is already in iTunes connect (which it is). So how do I change it from 1.0.0 to 1.1 in Organizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just figured it out but just in case anyone else doesn't know in Xcode click on Product --> Archive. Then it'll change the version number in Organizer automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the version of the build in the tab Targets > Identity > Version. 
Make sure to change the build and the version.[image]